# Setting up Laravel, getting PDO and permission problems

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, pdo

So on my linux AWS instance, I am trying to install a laravel application and am running into an awful amount of permission problems. 
By default, when I cloned my project into var/www/, the owner was Root. I changed the owner to apache, and added ec2-user to apache. From what I've read, this seems correct. 
From there, I tried to run php composer.phar install, which resulted in a permissions error unless I ran it sudo, and then the error was that "Class 'PDO' not found in /var/www/Mumble/app/config/database.php". 
So from there, it looked like PDO wasn't installed, so I used yum to install it, which got me the typical laravel error log, but it is now saying "could not find driver". Looking at php info, pdo is configured for mysqli. Could that be my problem? Does anybody know of some places I could look for resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, the latest version of laravel is 4.3, compatible with **PHP >= 5.4** (Source: [Laravel Installation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#server-requirements)).

The bad news is, the yum package of apache on AWS comes with **PHP 5.3**. Check your php version using `php phpinfo()` in your ssh console.

If you have the proper PHP version, you will have to make sure PHP is running underneath the user `apache`.

Go to `/etc/php.ini` and search for the parameter `user=`. Make sure it says `user=apache`, and `group=apache`.

If all of this checks out, your final step is to make sure that your `/app/storage` directories are on a `777` permission with owner being `apache`. Only laravel uses these for internal purposes, so it's alright.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to give the permission to access, is it accessible the /var/www directory?

if not try this,

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

for secure permission use 775 for the directories.

perhaps permission you need to set:

```
          # Set group to www-data
           sudo chgrp www-data /var/www
          # Make it writable for the group
          sudo chmod 775 /var/www
         # Set GID to www-data for all sub-folders
          sudo chmod g+s /var/www
         # Add your username to www-data group
         sudo usermod -a -G www-data username
        # Finally change ownership to username
         sudo chown username /var/www/
        # Your account shouldn't have any more permission issues
```

Note: please read about the file permission before you go further .

Comment: Wouldn't this be a big security risk? (I am new to really managing permissions, my main concern with this project is security of the application)

Comment: well it depends on your situation who will be able to read/write/execute the permission.

Comment: but if you are concern about the security, use 775 for the directory or for the file 664

Comment: alright I edited the command including the good security practice and you can have a look for the permission issue : http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Permissions.html

Comment: I understand the permission changes you have listed here, the problem here is that www-data isn't a group. Apache is running as User=Apache, Group=Apache. I changed Group to www-data, but from here I don't really know how to add it to etc/group correctly. I had seen somebody post those commands somewhere, and when I ran it, I ran it with apache in place of www-data, is that my problem?

Comment: Ok, made new group www-data, and that is what apache is using now. var/www is now owned by www-data, the user is ec2-user, so that looks correct. Also changed ran chown -R ec2-user:www-data ProjectFolder. The current error now is file_put_contents(/var/www/Project/app/storage/sessions/891542955df81abb1cd4ce39312193509e5cbe26): failed to open stream: Permission denied